# Introduction to Statistical Learning, Chapter 3,Ex 3.7.7: Proofing equality of $ R^2=Cor^2$ in simple linear regression. Figuring out the algebra

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

I am a hobby mathematican without any formal training.
Currently I am chewing through 'An Introduction to Statistical Learning', 1st Ed. (abbreviated: ISLR, https://www.statlearning.com/). Now I am stuck on an algebraic proof in the linear regression exercise chapter 3, specifically 3.7.7.

As this is a somewhat 'uphill' difficulty, I have not made much progress on the desired proof.

The excercise states:

"It is claimed in the text that in the case of simple linear regression of $Y$ onto $X$, the $ R^2 $ statistic (3.17) is equal to the square of the correlation between $X$ and $Y $(3.18). Prove that this is the case. For simplicity, you may assume that $ \bar{x}=\bar{y}=0 $".

I have come this far up to now:

Excercise 3.7.7:

Prove that $ R^2 = Cor^2 $

DEFINITIONS:

$ \bar{x} \equiv \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i }, $

$ \bar{y} \equiv \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i }, $

$
\hat{\beta}_1 =
  \frac
  { \sum_{i=1}^n{ (x_i - \bar{x}) (y_i - \bar{y}) } }
  { \sum_{i=1}^n{ (x_i - \bar{x})^2               } },
$

$ \hat{\beta}_0 = \bar{y} - \hat{\beta}_1 \bar{x}, $

$
\hat{y}_i
=
\hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 x_i
=
\hat{\beta}_0 +
  \frac
  { \sum_{i=1}^n{ (x_i - \bar{x}) (y_i - \bar{y}) } }
  { \sum_{i=1}^n{ (x_i - \bar{x})^2               } }
  x_i
=
\bar{y} -
  \frac
    { \sum_{i=1}^n{ (x_i - \bar{x}) (y_i - \bar{y}) } }
    { \sum_{i=1}^n{ (x_i - \bar{x})^2               } }
  \bar{x} +
  \frac
    { \sum_{i=1}^n{ (x_i - \bar{x}) (y_i - \bar{y}) } }
    { \sum_{i=1}^n{ (x_i - \bar{x})^2               } }
  x_i,
$

$ RSS = \sum_{i=1}^n { (y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2 }, $

$ TSS = \sum_{i=1}^n { (y_i - \bar{y}  )^2 }, $

$
R^2
=
\frac{TSS - RSS}{TSS}
=
1 - \frac{RSS}{TSS}
=
1 - \frac
  { \sum_{i=1}^n { (y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2 } }
  { \sum_{i=1}^n { (y_i - \bar{y}  )^2 } },
$

$
Cor
=
\frac
  { \sum_{i=1}^n { (x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y}) } }
  {
    \sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^n { (x_i-\bar{x})^2 } }
    \sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^n { (y_i-\bar{y})^2 } }
  }
=
\frac
  { \sum_{i=1}^n { (x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y}) } }
  {
    \sqrt{
      \sum_{i=1}^n { (x_i-\bar{x})^2 }
      \sum_{i=1}^n { (y_i-\bar{y})^2 }
    }
  }
$

$
Cor^2
=
\left(
  \frac
    { \sum_{i=1}^n { (x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y}) } }
    {
      \sqrt{
        \sum_{i=1}^n { (x_i-\bar{x})^2 }
        \sum_{i=1}^n { (y_i-\bar{y})^2 }
      }
    }
\right)^2
=
\frac
  { \left( \sum_{i=1}^n { (x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y}) } \right)^2 }
  {
    \left( \sqrt{
      \sum_{i=1}^n { (x_i-\bar{x})^2 }
      \sum_{i=1}^n { (y_i-\bar{y})^2 }
    } \right)^2
  }
=
\frac
  { \left( \sum_{i=1}^n { (x_i-\bar{x}) (y_i-\bar{y}) } \right)^2 }
  {
    \sum_{i=1}^n { (x_i-\bar{x})^2 }
    \sum_{i=1}^n { (y_i-\bar{y})^2 }
  }
$

TO PROVE:

$ R^2 = Cor^2 $, with $ \bar{x} = \bar{y} = 0 $. Initial expansion:

$
\hat{y}_i
=
\bar{y} -
  \frac
    { \sum_{i=1}^n{ (x_i - \bar{x}) (y_i - \bar{y}) } }
    { \sum_{i=1}^n{ (x_i - \bar{x})^2            } }
  \bar{x} +
  \frac
    { \sum_{i=1}^n{ (x_i - \bar{x}) (y_i - \bar{y}) } }
    { \sum_{i=1}^n{ (x_i - \bar{x})^2            } }
  x_i
=
0 -
  \frac
    { \sum_{i=1}^n{ (x_i - 0) (y_i - 0) } }
    { \sum_{i=1}^n{ (x_i - 0)^2     } }
  0 +
  \frac
    { \sum_{i=1}^n{ (x_i - 0) (y_i - 0) } }
    { \sum_{i=1}^n{ (x_i - 0)^2     } }
  x_i
=
\frac
  { \sum_{i=1}^n{ x_i y_i   } }
  { \sum_{i=1}^n{ x_i^2 } }
x_i
$

$
1 - \frac
  { \sum_{i=1}^n { (y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2 } }
  { \sum_{i=1}^n { (y_i - \bar{y}  )^2 } }
=
\frac
  { \left( \sum_{i=1}^n { (x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y}) } \right)^2 }
  {
    \sum_{i=1}^n { (x_i-\bar{x})^2 }
    \sum_{i=1}^n { (y_i-\bar{y})^2 }
  },
$

$
1 - \frac
  { \sum_{i=1}^n { (y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2 } }
  { \sum_{i=1}^n { (y_i - 0         )^2 } }
=
\frac
  { \left( \sum_{i=1}^n { (x_i-0)(y_i-0) } \right)^2 }
  {
    \sum_{i=1}^n { (x_i-0)^2 }
    \sum_{i=1}^n { (y_i-0)^2 }
  },
$

$
1 - \frac
  { \sum_{i=1}^n { (y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2 } }
  { \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 } }
=
\frac
  { \left( \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i y_i } \right)^2 }
  {
    \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i^2 }
    \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 }
  },
$

$
\boxed{
1 - \frac
  { \sum_{i=1}^n {
    \left(
      y_i -
      \frac
        { \sum_{i=1}^n{ x_i y_i } }
        { \sum_{i=1}^n{ x_i^2   } }
      x_i
    \right)^2 }
  }
  { \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 } }
=
\frac
  { \left( \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i y_i } \right)^2 }
  {
    \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i^2 }
    \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 }
  }
}
$

Ok, so now I want to prove the equality of the boxed formula.
And that is were I start to stumble. I manage to make a couple of transformations, however I can only achieve a common denominator between the two. The top part of the vulgar fraction escapes me.

Here is what I have tried:

RHS equals to:

$
\frac
  { \left( \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i y_i } \right)^2 }
  { \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i^2 } \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 } }
$

Transformations for LHS:

T0:
$
1 - \frac
  { \sum_{i=1}^n {
    \left(
      y_i -
      \frac
        { \sum_{i=1}^n{ x_i y_i } }
        { \sum_{i=1}^n{ x_i^2   } }
      x_i
    \right)^2 }
  }
  { \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 } }
$

T1:
$
\frac
  {
    \left( \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 } \right)
    -
    \sum_{i=1}^n {
      \left(
        y_i -
        \frac
          { \sum_{i=1}^n{ x_i y_i } }
          { \sum_{i=1}^n{ x_i^2   } }
        x_i
      \right)^2
    }
  }
  { \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 } }
$

T2:
$
\frac
  {
    \left( \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 } \right)
    -
    \sum_{i=1}^n {
      \left(
        y_i -
        \frac
          { x_i \sum_{i=1}^n{ x_i y_i } }
          {     \sum_{i=1}^n{ x_i^2   } }
      \right)^2
    }
  }
  { \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 } }
$

T3:
$
\frac
  {
    \left( \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 } \right)
    -
    \sum_{i=1}^n {
      \left(
        \frac
          {
            \left( y_i \sum_{i=1}^n{ x_i^2   } \right)
            -
            \left( x_i \sum_{i=1}^n{ x_i y_i } \right)
          }
          { \sum_{i=1}^n{ x_i^2 } }
      \right)^2
    }
  }
  { \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 } }
$

T4:
$
\frac
  {
    \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i^2 }
    \left(
      \left( \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 } \right)
      -
      \sum_{i=1}^n {
        \left(
          \frac
            {
              \left( y_i \sum_{i=1}^n{ x_i^2   } \right)
              -
              \left( x_i \sum_{i=1}^n{ x_i y_i } \right)
            }
            { \sum_{i=1}^n{ x_i^2 } }
        \right)^2
      }
    \right)
  }
  {
    \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i^2 }
    \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 }
  }
$

T5:
$
\frac
  {
    \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i^2 }
    \left(
      \left( \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 } \right)
      -
      \sum_{i=1}^n {
        \left(
          \left(
            \left( y_i \sum_{i=1}^n{ x_i^2   } \right)
            -
            \left( x_i \sum_{i=1}^n{ x_i y_i } \right)
          \right)
          \frac
            { 1 }
            { \sum_{i=1}^n{ x_i^2 } }
        \right)^2
      }
    \right)
  }
  {
    \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i^2 }
    \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 }
  }
$

... and here I am running massively out of ideas. I can see the term $ \left( \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i y_i } \right)^2 $ in the top, but no idea how to isolate it and remove the rest.

Does anyone have any pointers to get me back on the right road?

-terminal

Answer (score 1):

So, after tons of headscratching, I think I have arrived at a solution. Big thanks to V. Vancak with this, as he pushed me thinking into the right direction =)

My solution looks like this (feel free to correct me):

RHS:
$
\frac
  { \left( \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i y_i } \right)^2 }
  {
    \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i^2 }
    \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 }
  }
$

LHS with transformations:

T0:
$
1 -
\frac
  {
    \sum_{i=1}^n {
      \left(
        y_i -
        \frac
          { \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i y_i } }
          { \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i^2   } }
        x_i
      \right)^2
    }
  }
  { \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 } }
$

T1:
$
\frac
  {
    \left( \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 } \right) -
    \sum_{i=1}^n {
      \left(
        y_i -
        \frac
          { \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i y_i } }
          { \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i^2   } }
        x_i
      \right)^2
    }
  }
  { \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 } }
$

T2:
$
\frac
  {
    \sum_{i=1}^n {
      y_i^2 -
      \left(
        y_i -
        \frac
          { \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i y_i } }
          { \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i^2   } }
        x_i
      \right)^2
    }
  }
  { \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 } }
$

T3:
$
\frac
  {
    \sum_{i=1}^n {
      y_i^2 -
      y_i^2 +
      \left( - \frac
        { \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i y_i } }
        { \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i^2   } } \right)^2
      x_i^2
    }
  }
  { \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 } }
$

T4:
$
\frac
  {
    \sum_{i=1}^n {
      \left( - \frac
        { \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i y_i } }
        { \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i^2   } } \right)^2
      x_i^2
    }
  }
  { \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 } }
$

T5:
$
\frac
  {
    \left( - \frac
      { \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i y_i } }
      { \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i^2   } } \right)^2
    \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i^2 }
  }
  { \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 } }
$

T6:
$
\frac
  {
    \frac
      { \left( \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i y_i } \right)^2 }
      { \left( \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i^2   } \right)^2 }
    \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i^2 }
  }
  { \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 } }
$

T7:
$
\frac
  {
    \frac
      {
        \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i^2 }
        \left( \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i y_i } \right)^2
      }
      { \left( \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i^2   } \right)^2 }
  }
  { \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 } }
$

T8:
$
\frac
  {
    \frac
      { \left( \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i y_i } \right)^2 }
      { \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i^2 } }
  }
  { \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 } }
$

T9:
$
\frac
  { \left( \sum_{i=1}^n{ x_i y_i } \right)^2 }
  {
    \sum_{i=1}^n { x_i^2 }
    \sum_{i=1}^n { y_i^2 }
  }
$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $R^2 = \frac{SSreg}{SST} = \frac{\sum( \hat y_i - \bar y ) ^ 2}{\sum( y_i - \bar y ) ^ 2} $. You can easily (by replacing $\hat y_i$ with $\hat{\beta_0} + \hat \beta_1 x_i$) show that $\sum( \hat y_i - \bar y ) ^ 2 = \hat \beta_1 ^2 \sum( x_i - \bar x ) ^ 2$. Now, use the fact that the OLS of $\beta_1$ is
$$
\hat \beta_1 = \frac{\sum(  y_i - \bar y )(  x_i - \bar x ) }{ \sum(  x_i - \bar x )^2},
$$
by plugging it in $\hat \beta_1 ^2 \sum( x_i - \bar x ) ^ 2 /\sum( y_i - \bar y ) ^ 2 $ you'll get
$$
\frac{\left(\sum(  y_i - \bar y )(  x_i - \bar x )\right)^2}{\left(\sum(  x_i - \bar x )^2 \sum(  y_i - \bar y )^2 \right)^2 }
$$
which is the square of the Pearson corr. coefficient $r_{xy}$.

Comment: Ok, so let me try and understand:

in your definition of R^2, the statement is missing the 1 - RSS/TSS? In the book it is defined differently?

I will try and work out the ∑(̂ −¯)^2=̂^2∑(−¯)^2. More of this later.

With the acronym OLS you mean ordinary least squares?

Comment: 1. Recall that $SST = SSres + SSreg$, thus $1 - \frac{SSreg}{SST} = \frac{SST - SSres}{SST} = 1 - \frac{SSres}{SST}$, where $SSres$ is the residuals sum of squares, i.e., $RSS$ using your acronym. 
2.  Yes, OLS is the ordinary least squares.

Comment: OK now, I have worked through this, and the definition of R-squared by explained sum of squares divided by total sum of squares (R^2 = ESS/TSS) is (of course) valid, but the question actually asks about another definition as the basis.

Nevertheless, I will try and prove it through this way as well. More about this later.